# Passing an empty function into a React component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a React component; for example:

```
export class Component1 extends Component<IProps, IState> {
```

One of the props that it accepts is a function:

```
export interface IProps {    
    a: number,
    b: number,
    onMouseClick: () => void
}
```

So, when I use this component, I can do something like this:

```
<Component1 onMouseClick={() => this.DoStuff()} a={1} b={2} />
```

But what if I want to pass a null function in, so that the function does nothing on Mouse Click; for example:

```
<Component1 onMouseClick={() => void} a={1} b={2} />
```

Typescript moans at me, saying that it expects an expression.  I can declare an empty function; like this:

```
<Component1 onMouseClick={() => function(){}} a={1} b={2} />
```

Is there a nicer way that declaring an empty function?  I'm also a little unclear why I can assign the property `onMouseClick` to void in the IProps definition, but not when using the component.

Comment: `() => {}`? `() => void` is a *type* for a void function, hence its usage in the interface, not actually a function definition.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`() => void` is a type as far as typescript is concerned (and is actually a syntax error in Javascript). You should try `() => void 0` which is a function that returns undefined

```
<Component1 onMouseClick={() => void 0} a={1} b={2} />
```

Or if you want to allow `null` or be optional change the type of the prop to include `null`, although you will need extra checking in the component

```
export interface IProps {    
    a: number,
    b: number,
    onMouseClick?: () => void // ? makes it optional
}
<Component1 a={1} b={2} /> // no error
```

Answer (score 8):

The `void` is an operator in JavaScript and it has to be followed by an expression. So `() => void` is not valid callback definition. Noop function looks like this `() => {}` or `() => undefined` and can be used in jsx like this:

```
<Component1 onMouseClick={() => {}}  a={1} b={2}/>
```

But I would rather make `onMouseClick optional, it is much more convenient and obvious for a consumer of the component

```
interface IProps {    
   a: number,
   b: number,
   onMouseClick?: () => void
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
export interface IProps {    
    a: number,
    b: number,
    onMouseClick?: () => void
}
```

or

```
export interface IProps {    
    a: number,
    b: number,
    onMouseClick: () => void | null
}
```

Comment: The second method uses Union Types: 
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html

Answer (score 0):

you can make it optional

```
export interface IProps {    
    a: number,
    b: number,
    onMouseClick?: () => void 
}
```

and probably you want to do default props with default implementation so you won't have to check if onMouseClick is a function every time you use it

```
class ... extends React.Component<...>{
 static defaultProps = {
  onMouseClick: () => null,
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be useful taking into account linters

```
<Component1 onMouseClick={() => void undefined} a={1} b={2} />
```